# Can nextjs hosted on vercel listen to streams?

Tags: next.js, stream, twitter-api-v2

I am building a project on [nextJS](https://nextjs.org/) and hosting it on [vercel](https://vercel.com/). I want to listen to twitter streams. Can nextjs hosted on vercel listen to streams or do I have to use a server like [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/)?